# Where clause not working on a SQLite Join request

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I need all the unique values of ParteB field on ActPartB table matching the same IDNumber with userActTable but only for the condition of some userIDNumber (on userActTable)

The full sql string with the "WHERE"

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ParteB FROM ActParteB INNER JOIN userAct ON IDNumber = IDNumber WHERE userAct.userIDNumber = ? order by ParteB asc"
```

Then I add

```
cmdConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIDNumber", NumberOfActiveuser)
```

The program run with no debugging error but it shows all the unique fields of ActPartB no matter the value of userIDNumber. The value os userIDNumber is fine because.

Is just that the WHERE is "ignored"

This

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ParteB FROM ActParteB INNER JOIN userAct ON IDNumber = IDNumber WHERE userAct.userIDNumber = ? order by ParteB asc"
```

Produces the same ouput of this

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ParteB FROM ActParteB INNER JOIN userAct ON IDNumber = IDNumber order by ParteB asc"
```

**What is wrong with the Where clause?**

Full code here:

```
Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnStr)

Try
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmdConnection As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

    Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ParteB FROM ActParteB INNER JOIN userAct ON IDNumber = IDNumber WHERE userAct.userIDNumber = ? order by ParteB asc"

            cmdConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIDNumber", NumberOfActiveUser)

            Dim readerParteB As SQLiteDataReader = cmdConnection.ExecuteReader()

            ParteBComboBox.Items.Clear()

            Try
                While (readerParteB.Read())
                    ParteBComboBox.Items.Add(readerParteB("ParteB"))
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try

End Using
```

Comment: I've never used the SQLite ADO.NET provider but I notice that you are writing your SQL with a positional parameter.  Do you know whether that provider supports named parameters, i.e. can you use "@userIDNumber" in your SQL instead of "?"?

Comment: Because what? And show the entire querying code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, I use parameters on SQlite for record and request like "Dim sql = "INSERT INTO usersTable (userName) VALUES (@paramUserName)"" with no problem. It's the first time I'm using JOIN and WHERE.

Comment: @CL full code added

Comment: Shouldn't `INNER JOIN userAct ON IDNumber = IDNumber` be `INNER JOIN userAct  ON userAct.IDNumber = ActParteB.IDNumber`?

Comment: @Jinx88909 RIGHT!!! The mistake was the part "ON IDNumber = IDNumber" both tables with the same name of the field, so the solution as marked by Jinx88909 was the use of the complete Table.Field name. Using `ON ActParteB.IDNumber = userAct.IDNumber` works fine! How can I mark the answer of Jinx88909 as valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim cmdConnection As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

Dim sql = "..."
```

Your command does not work correctly because it uses a different SQL string (the value of some other `sql` variable that you declared in some previous part of the code).

Furthermore, as mentioned by Jinx88909, you must add the table names to the join to specify which `IDNumber` column you mean (when in doubt, the database will of course choose the wrong one):

```sql
... JOIN userAct ON userAct.IDNumber = ActParteB.IDNumber ...
                    ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, when the column names are the same, better use USING, which automatically gets the column from both tables:

```sql
... JOIN userAct USING (IDNumber) ...
```

Comment: Even changing Dim sql = "...." for Dim sqlB = "...." I get the same. The request works minus the WHERE userAct.userIDNumber = ? filter. I'm confused about that.

Comment: I fixed the code on the answer, first the Dim Sql an then the DIM cmdConnection

Comment: I don't understand why CL edited the code. Even with the Dim Sql before the Dim cmdConnection the WHERE clause is not working.

Comment: This is not a forum; don't change the question in a way that would invaldate answers.

Comment: I lost the last edition of your answer, and yes, that was the solution. Marked as the solution. Thanks.